# Linker errors while using the FirebaseCrashlytics(FIRCrashlytics) framework in iOS

Tags: crashlytics

I am facing the linker errors while using the FirebaseCrashlytics(FIRCrashlytics) framework.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRCrashlytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in xxxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using the FirebaseAnalytics as well. But I didn't face any issue with this framework events are tracking as expected. I have added this Framework (FirebaseCrashlytics) to the same targets as FirebaseAnalytics. But with FirebaseCrashlytics framework I am facing this issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue with xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0):

[Other Link Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mMcd.png)

Try to add in "Other Link Flags" all flags like in the image. This helped me.